# Is it possible to force to false or true the App.config transformation with arguments on Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to force the TransformOnBuild to false using MSBuild parameters in Azure DevOps?

So I Use Azure DevOps Pipeline to build a clickOnce application for a staging environment

[image]

Here is my MSBuild Arguments

```
/target:publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:InstallURL=http://app-staging.example.com/ /p:PublishURL=http://app-staging.example.com/ /p:UpdateEnabled=true  /p:UpdateMode=Foreground  /p:ProductName="App Staging" /p:OutputPath="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Publish\\"
```

Is it possible to force to false or true the App.config transformation with arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

Azure Pipelines [supports conditional steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). Find these under `Control Options` in any build step.

**How** you build your custom conditions will depend on what triggers your step to true/false.

The screenshot has an example of how we control a build step based on a build variable (defined in the `variables` tab of the pipeline).

[image]